# When I use \usepackage{pstricks-add} the vowels with accent are eliminated

Tags: accents, pstricks-add

I have typed this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\newtheorem{definicion}{Definici\'on}[chapter]
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corolario}{Corolario}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposicion}{Proposici\'on}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{ejemplo}{Ejemplo}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Mi tesis}
Matemáticas
\end{document}
```

I get:

> Captulo 1
>   Mi tesis
>   Matemticas

But when I eliminate `\usepackage{pstricks-add}`, I get:

> Capítulo 1
>   Mi tesis
>   Matemáticas

I need use that package but I think that eliminate the vowels with accent.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `pstricks-add`, actually. You are missing the `fontenc` package. Just put `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` after `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik that shouldn't happen?

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and then show the file list from the log. If I try your example program i get the accented vowels.